# Is there a double caret sign?

Tags: utf-8, symbols

Basically, is there a rotated right/left version of 《 》, such that the symbol would be pointing upward and not sideways.

It's for a visualization project and I tried the "^" sign but it's too narrow and it only occupies the upper space. I want something that's wider.

Answer (score 2):

I believe so..

Check the following links..

**PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL LEFT DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET**
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fe3d/index.htm

**PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET**
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fe3e/index.htm

Good luck.